# Select distinct from another select results

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I want to select distinct results from another select statement results
e.g;

```
select distinct from(select * from table)
```

following is result of inner select

```
testing department      9998901036      GOLD    
testing department      9998901036      GOLD
```

I want to get distinct from above select result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From your example, you could just do

```
select distinct * from table
```

But say you had some scenario where you wanted to distinct on some other results set, you could do

```
select distinct column1, column2 from (select * from table) T
```

Note that you have to alias your inner select

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct * 
from
(select * from table) t
```

Works - You just need to give your sub select a table alias.

You can also use a CTE.

```
;WITH t AS
(
SELECT * 
FROM table
)
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM t
```

Comment: What is meaning of this( You can also use a CTE.)

Comment: @Zain - CTE = Common Table Expression declared after `WITH` as in the second example I gave.